# Armature doesn't move with mesh

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

My mesh won't move with my armature. I think everything is properly attached, etc. It seems to only happen when I reposition the bones of the armature to correctly fit the mesh. It works prior.

I'm completely new at this, any advice would be helpful. Here is the .blend file.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rjt2zdv6owtqfst/why.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

They do move together, you just need to click or press enter to confirm and see the change.
If you want to see the mesh move in real time while you are moving it with the armature, disable *Delay Refresh* in the *Display* panel of your armature.